# RedirectToAction runs forever

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, redirect, history.js

I have trouble with redirects in MVC 3. Here is my form:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Client", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "sem.pivotAjaxSuccess" })) { ...form inputs... }
```

in the controller after successful I return redirect to action

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

everything looks good but GET in firebug continues forever. I can't post image because of Stackoverflow's limitations to new users.

OnSuccess function is

```
this.pivotAjaxSuccess = function (data) {
        if ($(data).filter('#main-pivot').length > 0) {
            $('#main-pivot').html($(data).filter('#main-pivot').html());
        }
        else {
            $('#main-pivot').html($(data));
        }

        parseElem('#main-pivot');
        setMenu('/' + this.url.substr(0, this.url.indexOf('?')).replace(History.getRootUrl(), ''));

        var requestUrl = this.url, title = $(data).filter('title').text();

        currentUrl = requestUrl.substr(0, requestUrl.indexOf('?'));
        History.pushState(null, title, requestUrl.substr(0, requestUrl.indexOf('?')));
    }
```

Comment: You might not be able to post an illustration, but you would still be able to post a link to it....

Comment: It seems you're calling a controller action from an ajax form, but the controller returns `RedirectToAction()`. Is that true?

Comment: @mnemosyn yes, it's true. I know it's wrong but how can I return another view?

Comment: You could return an action result that renders the view `return View("path/to/view.cshtml", model)`. The thing is that the `RedirectToAction` will send a redirected message over the pipe, no more. A browser would typically follow such a message automatically, but an AJAX call won't.